# SSIS Find & Reverse Function

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I am trying to get the date from the below filename using ssis expression.i get this file name from the variable

I have tried using findstring and reverse function but it still throwing cannot parse.

Any recommendtions pls

Variable

```
@[User::CurrentFile] : Z:\RETAIL DATA\HN_NLG\Supplier_report_by_Brand_Trend Micro_WC_20170327.xlsx
```

Need to get `20170327` and convert to `2017-03-27`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` and `SUBSTRING` to achieve this, use the following expression to get the expected output:

```
SUBSTRING(LEFT(right(@[User::CurrentFile],13),8),1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(LEFT(right(@[User::CurrentFile],13),8),5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(LEFT(right(@[User::CurrentFile],13),8),7,2)
```

If `@[User::CurrentFile] = 'Z:\RETAIL DATA\HN_NLG\Supplier_report_by_Brand_Trend Micro_WC_20170327.xlsx'` you will get `2017-03-27`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below, may be in a exec sql task or script and assign it to a variable for using further.

```
 select Cast(CONVERT(date,
  Reverse(Substring(Reverse('Z:\RETAIL DATA\HN_NLG\Supplier_report_by_Brand_Trend Micro_WC_20170327.xlsx'),
 CHARINDEX('.',Reverse('Z:\RETAIL DATA\HN_NLG\Supplier_report_by_Brand_Trend Micro_WC_20170327.xlsx'),1)+1,
8))) as varchar(10))
```

Comment: Thanks Kapil for your help